# What is the use of an IIFE in this example?

Tags: javascript, iife

I know what an IIFE is and that its purpose is to provide some form of encapsulation. The last few days I have been watching a video tutorial in which they use this pattern:

```
var ViewModel = (function(){
  var model = function(){
    //...
  };
  return model;
})();

//in the same or another file:
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

I don't see the advantage of using an IIFE here. What is the advantage over doing this:

```
var ViewModel = function(){ 
    //...
  return model;
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, there is no advantage.

In a more general case, it allows the creation of scoped variables for the use of the function(s) that are returned.